# Sleep is limiting thread performance

Tags: c++, pthreads, sleep

I have a multi-threaded system where I have **x** number of threads sending packets on to a network simultaneously.

This all works fine any dandy, however some of the threads I want to limit their speed in order to send packets at a certain rate.

So I put a sleep into my packet injection loop and it nicely slows down the thread for small speeds (1 Mbps up to around 70Mbps), however if I want to limit it to 1Gbps then I just can't reach that speed with the sleep in place. Now I know it can reach that speed because if I remove the sleep from all of the threads they can inject at nearly 2Gbps each.

So as a test I replaced my sleep with

```
usleep(0);
```

I believed that this should enable the speed to go back up to full again, but it doesn't it still remains limited (Only reaches about 1/20th of max speed). So my only current explanation is that even for a sleep(0), the thread yields and therefore none of the threads are getting enough execution time.

So, sorry for the long explanation, but is there a better way to sleep my threads without causing such a performance penalty?

I have tried, usleep and nanosleep and same results on both. Same setup for all tests, i.e. number of threads

System: CentOS, pthreads, g++ 4.4.6

Comment: A context switch (having one thread leave the processor for another) is an expensive thing. Are you sure you couldn't solve the issue without thread switching, e.g. with a priority queue?

Comment: @thiton I haven't used a priority queue before but I'll certainly look into whether that could be used - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding your `sleep` calls every `n` packets injected, instead of simply on each iteration. That way, you don't incur the thread-switch penalty on every packet injected, and you can control the amount of sleep done in a fairly fine-grained way.

Comment: Nice idea, I may give that a go and see what happens!

Comment: Just thought I'd update to say that your solution works really nicely! Can't believe I didn't think to do that in first place :)

Answer (score 1):

It may well be the function call itself which is slowing things down (either because of the function call set up and tear down, or because something in the call is doing other stuff which is slowing you down).

You may want to consider a line like:

```
if (delay > 0) usleep (delay);
```

so that the function isn't called *at all* if no delay is desired.

You could even encapsulate that into:

```
#define usleepIfNonZero(n) { if (n > 0) usleep (n); }
```

with the usual caveats applied to macro parameters of course (don't pass something like `x++` or you'll find it incrementing twice).

---

Alternatively, simply maintain a packet count and a base time to use for calculations and have the *average* speed worked out. For example:

```
#define PACKETS_PER_SEC 25

baseTime = now() - 1; // prevent divide by zero later on 
packetCount = 0;
while (1) {
    sendPacket (nextPacket());
    packetCount++;
    secondCount = now() - baseTime;
    while (packetCount / secondCount > PACKETS_PER_SEC) {
        sleep (1);
        secondCount = now() - baseTime;
    }
}
```

This will automatically converge to a point where your packets per second reach 25 but of course you may *still* find that the processing doesn't allow you to reach full speed.

Comment: Yes, I did implement this and it works great if I just want max speed on each thread but if I want to limit the thread speed in any way it's still an issue. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that also seems like a good viable alternative

Answer (score 0):

You said "So my only current explanation is that even for a sleep(0), the thread yields and therefore none of the threads are getting enough execution time."

As per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/usleep.html if usleep(...) get 0, then it has no impact so, no thread context switch should occur if we pass it 0!

Have you verified usleep(0); really causing problem and if you comment out this call, everything works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on sleep in this way to do throttling. You're not on a real-time system.

Instead send bursts of X data where you want to send X data/time unit, where time unit is maybe a ms or something like that. Then after sending each burst figure out how much time you need to sleep to reach the average bandwidth that you want and sleep that much. Don't do this calculation on the last burst, but instead record the start time of each burst with high precision timing, and calculate amortized over a larger set of bursts, say the last 100 bursts or something like that. This way you average out any overhead in context switching, system calls, stuff outside your main send loop, and also the delay in coming back to be the running process.

When you usleep(x) (x != 0) you are yielding and will simply be added somewhere in the run-queue, there is no guarantee how fast you will be a running process again on a non-real-time system. Therefore you have to amortize such variances in overhead over time.